# Forum with daily/weekly digest

Tags: php, forum

I need to migrate a forum (Drupal 6 with Advanced Forum) to a newer forum software and I currently lean towards MyBB or bbPress.
However, one of the features requested by the client are weekly digests (this is currently working in the old Drupal 6 forum).
I couldn't find an option/plugin for weekly digests in MyBB. I found a plugin for bbPress, but development was stopped 4 years ago.

Is there way to realize weekly digests in MyBB or bbPress? If not, are the other forum solutions that would be better suited?

Other requirements (besides the common forum functionalities):
 - PHP/MySQL
 - file upload (for posts and replies)
 - responsive (desktop and mobile)
 - preferably open source

Comment: How about "upgrading" from Drupal 6 (which is out of support) to Drupal 7, and use an appropriate set of contributed modules (Views, Rules, Answers, etc) to implement the equivalent of such "Advanced Forum"?

Comment: That was my first approach, but the upgrade didn't go as smooth as expected (mainly because of the way comments are handled). I then looked into other forum platforms and my impression was that Drupal for a forum is not that widely used. Therefore I wanted to switch to one of the commonly used platforms.